# Count records with values that belong to a set or group

Tags: mysql

How do I write a query that counts (totals) the number of values in a group for data spread across three tables?  For each reporter and report date, I’d like a count of the number of sightings where species codes is 10 or 20 (using IN because species group has lots of codes).

```
REPORTER TABLE
reporter_id | reporter_num
-----------------------------
1           | 1111
2           | 2222

REPORT TABLE
report_id | reporter_id | report_date
-------------------------------------
1         | 1           | 2022-09-05
2         | 1           | 2022-09-05
3         | 1           | 2022-09-05
4         | 1           | 2022-09-16
5         | 2           | 2022-09-22
6         | 2           | 2022-09-22

SIGHTING TABLE
sighting_id | species_code
------------------------
1           | 10          
2           | 55          
3           | 20          
4           | 35         
5           | 55 
6           | 20
```

This is essentially what I’m working with when the three tables are joined:

```
reporter_num | report_date | species_code
----------------------------------------
1111         | 2022-09-05  | 10
1111         | 2022-09-05  | 55
1111         | 2022-09-05  | 20
1111         | 2022-09-16  | 35
2222         | 2022-09-22  | 55
2222         | 2022-09-22  | 20
```

Query: for each reporter_num and report_date (one row per reporter_num and report_date), count the number of sightings where species_code is 10 or 20.  Expected results:

```
reporter_num | report_date | my_count
----------------------------------------
1111         | 2022-09-05  | 2
1111         | 2022-09-16  | 0
2222         | 2022-09-22  | 1
```

A count in my query gives the total number of records for each reporter_num and report_date which isn’t what I want:

```
select 
   reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date,
   count(sighting.species_code in (10, 20)) as my_count
from report
   inner join reporter on report.reporter_id = report.reporter_id
   inner join location on report.report_id = location.report_id
   inner join method on location.location_id = method.location_id
   left join sighting on method.method_id = sighting.method_id
group by
   reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date;
```

Query Results – my_count is total number of records, which is incorrect:

```
reporter_num | report_date | my_count
----------------------------------------
1111         | 2022-09-05  | 3
1111         | 2022-09-16  | 1
2222         | 2022-09-22  | 2
```

Tried a subquery and the counts in both the outer query and subquery are incorrect:

```
select
   reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date,
   count(my_table.my_count)
from report
   inner join reporter on report.reporter_id = reporter.reporter_id
   inner join (
      select 
         reporter.reporter_id, reporter.reporter_num,
         report.report_date, sighting.species_code as my_count
      from report
         [... see joins in above query ...]
      where sighting.species_code in (10, 20)
      ) as my_table on reporter.reporter_id = my_table.reporter_id
group by
   reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date;
```

I feel like I’m close but missing something (or a couple somethings).  Any suggestions?  Many thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and this fiddle to give us the `location` and `method` tables. Otherwise we can't tell how to relate the data you showed us to `sighting`, or what kind of combinatorial explosion takes place with the JOINs

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't using COUNT or COUNT(IF) correctly.  The IF has to be 1 if true and NULL if false; otherwise, it will add 1 even if the species code isn't in the species group.  The correct code:

```
select 
   reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date,
   count(if(sighting.species_code in (10, 20), 1, NULL)) as my_count
from report
   [... see joins in above query ...]
group by
   reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date;
```

The above will also return report dates that don't have any species in the species group, my_count will be zero for that case, which is what I want.

To exclude report dates with zero species in the species group, use count(*) in SELECT and filter for the species codes in WHERE.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT reporter_num, report_date,
LENGTH(gs) + 2 - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(',', gs, ','), ',(10|20),', 'len')) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date, GROUP_CONCAT(sighting.species_code) gs
    FROM report
    JOIN reporter ON report.reporter_id = reporter.reporter_id
    [... joins on location and method ...]
    JOIN sighting ON link.sighting_id = sighting.sighting_id
  GROUP BY reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date
) tbl;
```

Outputs:

```
| reporter_num | report_date | cnt |
|--------------|-------------|-----|
| 1111         | 2022-09-05  | 2   |
| 1111         | 2022-09-16  | 0   |
| 2222         | 2022-09-22  | 1   |
```

First creating an ad hoc, temporary table using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) and [`GROUP BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx):

```
SELECT reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date, GROUP_CONCAT(sighting.species_code) gs
  FROM report
  JOIN reporter ON report.reporter_id = reporter.reporter_id
  [... joins on location and method ...]
  JOIN sighting ON link.sighting_id = sighting.sighting_id
GROUP BY reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date
```

Outputs:

```
| reporter_num | report_date | gs       |
|--------------|-------------|----------|
| 1111         | 2022-09-05  | 10,55,20 |
| 1111         | 2022-09-16  | 35       |
| 2222         | 2022-09-22  | 55,20    |
```

Then counting occurrences of either 10 or 20 in the `GROUP_CONCAT`'ed `gs` column:

```
LENGTH(gs) + 2 - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(',', gs, ','), ',(10|20),', 'len'))
```

In this case using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) instead of [`REPLACE`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx) as is used in the [credited link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/finding-number-of-occurrences-of-a-specific-string-in-mysql).

---

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE reporter (
  reporter_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  reporter_num INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE report (
  report_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  reporter_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  report_date TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE report_sighting (
  report_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  sighting_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE link (
  report_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  sighting_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE sighting (
  sighting_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  species_code INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO reporter VALUES (1, 1111), (2, 2222);
INSERT INTO report VALUES (1, 1, '2022-09-05'), (2, 1, '2022-09-05'), (3, 1, '2022-09-05'), (4, 1, '2022-09-16'),
  (5, 2, '2022-09-22'), (6, 2, '2022-09-22');
INSERT INTO link VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6);
INSERT INTO sighting VALUES (1, 10), (2, 55), (3, 20), (4, 35), (5, 55), (6, 20);


-- fetch 
SELECT reporter_num, report_date,
LENGTH(gs) + 2 - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT(',', gs, ','), ',(10|20),', 'len')) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date, GROUP_CONCAT(sighting.species_code) gs
    FROM report
    JOIN reporter ON report.reporter_id = reporter.reporter_id
    JOIN link ON report.report_id = link.report_id
    JOIN sighting ON link.sighting_id = sighting.sighting_id
  GROUP BY reporter.reporter_num, report.report_date
) tbl;
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3ygv4cry2

Credit: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/finding-number-of-occurrences-of-a-specific-string-in-mysql